# Transpose columns to rows, show value_counts of former columns as column value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

Let's suppose I have this dataset.
Each variable can assume values between 1 and 5. The variables represent similar objects, so I would like to compare them across all data sets.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'dataset': ["ds1", "ds2", "ds3", "ds4", "ds5"], 
                   'var1': [1, 4, 5, 3, 1], 
                   'var2': [2, 1, 1, 2, 5],
                   'var3': [2, 1, 1, 2, 5]})
df
```

I want to transpose the df using .T and sum up the data as follows:

**rows:** each representing one variable (var1 to var3)
**columns 1 - 5** : representing values of these variables, each cell showing the total number of appearances of this value across all datasets (var1.value_counts)

**Example:** Row1 represents var1. Column1 shows "1" appears two times across all datasets, column2 shows 2 appears 0 times

**Expected outcome**

```
         1 2 3 4 5
var1     2 0 1 1 1
var2     2 2 0 0 1
var3     2 2 0 0 1
```

Maybe I need to use crosstab or pivot_table? Thanks!

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = (df.melt('dataset')
         .pivot_table(index='variable',
                      columns='value',
                      aggfunc='size',
                      fill_value=0)
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df1)
      1  2  3  4  5
var1  2  0  1  1  1
var2  2  2  0  0  1
var3  2  2  0  0  1
```

Or for all columns without first `value_counts` with transpose, replaced missing values to `0` and last converting all values to integers:

```
df = df.set_index('dataset').apply(pd.value_counts).T.fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
      1  2  3  4  5
var1  2  0  1  1  1
var2  2  2  0  0  1
var3  2  2  0  0  1
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I also apply something like (normalize=True) to show percentages across rows or even columns now?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `crosstab` works fine (or `pivot table` in @jezrael's solution), after `melt` :

```
tab = df.melt("dataset")

pd.crosstab(tab.variable, tab.value).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)


        1   2   3   4   5
var1    2   0   1   1   1
var2    2   2   0   0   1
var3    2   2   0   0   1
```

Yes, you can use the `normalize` argument, and choose if you want it via rows(index) or columns :

```
pd.crosstab(tab.variable, tab.value, normalize='all').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I also apply something like (normalize=True) to show percentages across rows or even columns now?

Comment: Yes, you can. the options for `normalize` are `all`, `index`, `columns`